# Como fazer menu com desenho diferente?

Tags: html, css

Bom galerinha do stack eu preciso fazer esse menu que está no wireframe, porém não sei quais comandos que uso para deixar a linha na diagonal.Segue a imagem abaixo:

[image: Wireframe]

OBS: Preciso fazer somente com HTML e CSS, agradeço desde já.E ignorem os números dentro do quadrado azul.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48152/css-div-diagonal

Answer (score 3):

Segue exemplo que poderia obter este resultado:

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 80px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.menu li:before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -70px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 150px solid #fff;
  border-right: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.menu li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu 01</li>
  <li>Menu 02</li>
  <li>Menu 03</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: E caso eu queira manter uma largura(tamanho) fixo?Pois quando coloco texto de diferentes tamanhos dentro ele acaba se ajustando e aumentando sozinho o tamanho da box.

Comment: @LoneTonberry, basta você dar um `width` fixo ao `.menu li` tendo em vista que irá quebrar se o texto interno for muito grande.

Answer (score 1):

Fazer a parte inclinada apenas com HTML e CSS pode levar a gambiarras que:

- vão voltar para te assombrar quando você tiver que dar manutenção;
- vão dar trabalho para ficarem minimamente não-ofensivas aos olhos em todos os tipos de telas e dispositivos.

Acho que para um caso simples desse não é problema - é até recomendável - utilizar imagens para fazer a parte inclinada das abas.

Apenas faça algo do tipo:

```
<tag>Item de menu</tag>
```

Onde `tag` é o tipo elemento que você achar melhor (div, li etc.)

E preencha os atributos `min-width`, `margin`, `padding`, `text-align`, `background-color` e `background-image` da li ao seu gosto.

Daí você usa uma .gif ou um .png como imagem de fundo alinhada à esquerda do elemento, e dá um fundo da mesma cor.