# Css Como deixar o Lado Direito da Div Inclinado?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-transições

Estou com uma demanda na qual preciso deixar somente um lado direito de uma div inclinado, ou seja, na diagonal. Como consigo esse efeito?

Ao pesquisar, vi que poderia usar o código abaixo para inclinar a div, mas o meu problema se dá no fato do código inclinar toda a div, mas que quero que apenas o lado direito seja inclinado.

```
-ms-transform: skew(30deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(30deg); 
transform: skew(30deg); 
transform-origin: bottom left;
```

Eis meu código CSS

```
.logo-topo{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);   
    float:left;
    height: 165px;
    margin-left: -138px;
    width: 299px;
    z-index: 805;   
    -ms-transform: skew(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(30deg); 
    transform: skew(-30deg); 
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    border-width: 10px 50px 90px;  
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [CSS DIV diagonal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48152/css-div-diagonal)

Comment: Se pretende somente inclinar o canto direito, basta rotacionar -10deg e compensar a diferença na margem

Comment: Obrigado Felipe Duarte, Era isso mesmo! adicionei os -10deg e compensei através do margin-left e resolveu obrigado!